# Confirmation delete data using sweetAlert with laravel 6

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to create delete confirmation in my app using sweet alert when I click to delete button so I am facing an error on console  **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function**

Please suggest on how to fix this error?

[image: error image]

**Controller**

```
                  public function destroy($id)
                  {
                  $delete = Digitizing::where('id', $id)->delete();
                  if ( $delete == 1) {
                  $success = true;
                  $message = "User deleted successfully";
                  } else {
                  $success = true;
                  $message = "User not found";
                  }        
                  }
```

**HTML view**

```
                           <a class="btn btn-danger" onclick="deleteConfirmation({{$digitizing- 
                           >id}})">Delete</a>



                             <script type="text/javascript">
                             function deleteConfirmation(id) {
                             swal({
                            title: "Delete?",
                            text: "Please ensure and then confirm!",
                            type: "warning",
                            showCancelButton: !0,
                            confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
                           cancelButtonText: "No, cancel!",
                           reverseButtons: !0
                           }).then(function (e) {

                         if (e.value === true) {
                         var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf- 
                        token"]').attr('content');

                         $.ajax({
                         type: 'POST',
                         url: "{{url('/delete')}}/" + id,
                         data: {_token: CSRF_TOKEN},
                         dataType: 'JSON',
                        success: function (results) {
                        if (results.success === true) {
                        swal("Done!", results.message, "success");
                        } else {
                        swal("Error!", results.message, "error");
                        }
                        }
                        });
                        } else {
                         e.dismiss;
                          }
                           }, function (dismiss) {
                           return false;
                           })
                           }
                           </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because of the `swal({` part of your code. 
Swal is the name of the class. You will want to replace it with `Swal.fire(`.

Additionaly, please note that your php code will return `$success = true;` in both scenarios. You might want tot update that as well.

Comment: Hi, I have used this Swal.fire( after that when I click to delete button just showing delete confirmation popup but data is no deleting.  please see this image https://ibb.co/WHjXQ3W

Comment: My answer fixed your posted problem. If you now have another problem, please tell us what the new problem is. What error(s) are you getting? Is your request hitting the backend? Something seems off with your URL `url: "{{url('/delete')}}/" + id,`, you're probably missing something else before `/delete`